# Frame escape behaving differently between page visit and in-page action triggering page visit

Tags: javascript, xss, google-translate

### My short question

Why doesn't this link work?

https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ja&tl=en&u=https://www.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp/web/all/top/BTmTopPage

### The long version

You will notice that https://www.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp/web/all/top/BTmTopPage contains this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (self === top) {
        var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
        antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
    } else {
        top.location = self.location; // this part is important!
    }
</script>
```

> If we are in a frame, escape the frame.

Now, when one visits Google Translate and enters https://www.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp/web/all/top/BTmTopPage as a page to translate, and clicks "Translate" (and maybe tells Google that the page is not English, but Japanese), one is redirected to

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp%2Fweb%2Fall%2Ftop%2FBTmTopPage

and from there, it redirects just fine to

https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=ja&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://www.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp/web/all/top/BTmTopPage&xid=...&usg=...

showing the translated web site.

Now, I would like to link to the translated site, which is possible for so many sites that don't escape iframes:

https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ja&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F

However, when I visit

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp%2Fweb%2Fall%2Ftop%2FBTmTopPage

(or the first link in this question), I am *not* redirected until I click search again, basically redirecting me to the same page once more and then to the translated website.

In the Console, I see things like this, so XSS protection seems to be involved:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://translate.google.com' from frame with URL 'https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=...'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.
>
> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to 'https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=...'

Why is that? What is the difference between visiting the page, and clicking a button to visit the same page? How can one redirect, but not the other? Can I do something about this? Could the `sandbox` parameter be of any help?

Comment: What if you remove that piece of code? What would the behavior be?

Comment: @JL-HN any suggestion as to how I can remove code from the patent platform website of the Japanese patent office? :) I get your point, and it would be a good one if it were my website - it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but if it is any help, internet explorer and Firefox have extremely weak XSS protection. If it sandboxes in chrome, it won't in Firefox and internet explorer. Besides, a normal website can't prevent you from opening a link, so it is probably your browser that is causing problems.

Comment: Nice idea! The link does indeed work in Chrome and Firefox Klar on Android, so maybe this is a Chrome-on-Desktop-specific implementation issue.

Comment: It seems it is not - the link behaves identical to desktop Chrome in desktop IE and desktop Firefox.